# How to set collection View to nth element

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 1 ViewController and it will launch another ViewController which has a CollectionView.

I want to set the uicollecitonView to a specified element when it first start.
In previous thread someone suggests me to use ' set the contentOffset of the collection view to (collection view width) * selectedRow'. But I can't get that to work.

In my prepareForSegue function, I have added:

```
  x = Float(indexPath.row) * 375.0 // 375 is the width of 1 cell
  var point = CGPointMake(CGFloat(x), 0)
  println ("***x=")
  println (x)
  detailController.collectionView?.setContentOffset(point , animated: false)
where detailController is UICollectionViewController.
```

and in the UICollectionViewDataSource of my collection View, I always see it get the 0th element, not the nth element

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as DetailViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        println("DetailViewController in cellForItemAtIndexPath()")
        println(indexPath.row)
     cell.myitem = allItems[indexPath.row]
return cell }
```

And I always see cellForItemAtIndexPath trying to get 0th element of the allItems (that is the whole collections of all my objects.

Any idea to solve this?

Update:

Thanks. I tried  I get this exception: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path:  {length = 1, path = 4}'

I am sure I have 26 items in my list. Why there is only 1 when I want to scroll it to 4th element:

```
class MyViewCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            println("MyViewCollectionViewController viewDidAppear")

            println("items.count")
            println(items?.count)  // print out 26

            println(index) // print out 4

            var newIndex = NSIndexPath(index: self.index)
            self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(newIndex, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Left, animated: false)
        }
}
```

Comment: who not use scrollToItemAtIndexPath? set this in viewDidAppear for the collectionView

Comment: You can't set the content offset in prepareForSegue, because the new controller's view hasn't been loaded yet, which will make any outlets nil. Try moving the code you have there into the collectionViewController's viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually a collection view uses index paths with a section and an item.  Try creating `newIndex` this way in `viewDidAppear`:

```
let newIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem:self.index inSection:0)
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixes my problem. But I notice that in my view, it first display the content of my 0th item before the 4th item appears. Is there anyway to make it not showing 0th first?

Comment: Try calling `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidAppear`.